# How to print information from /proc/pid/

Tags: c, linux

Second question today the first one really helped.

So this is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/procfs.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <pwd.h>
char *getWaitChannel(int pid);
char *getPath(int pid);
char *getUserName(int uid);
int getBytes(int pid);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long x;
    if (argc < 2){
    //error message
}
    x = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    printf("Good 1\n");
    get_info(x, argc, argv);
}
int get_info(pid_t pid)
{
    char path[40], line[100], *p, stateChar[100], Name[100];
    FILE* statusf;
    char buf[100];
    printf("This is pid %d\n", pid);
    int uid, vM;
    snprintf(path, 40, "/proc/%d/status", pid);
    statusf = fopen(path, "r");
    if(statusf == NULL)
        return -1;

    while(fgets(buf,sizeof buf, statusf) != NULL){

    sscanf(buf, "State:  %s", stateChar);
    sscanf(buf, "Name:  %s", Name);
    sscanf(buf, "Uid:     %d", &uid);
    sscanf(buf, "VmPeak: %d", &vM);

}
    char *channel = getWaitChannel(pid);
    char *full_path = getPath(pid);
    char *user = getUserName(uid);
    int b = getBytes(pid);
    printf("State: %s\n", stateChar);
    printf("Name: %s\n", Name);
    printf("Uid: %d\n", uid);
    printf("Username: %s\n", user);
    printf("Max Virtual Memory: %d\n", vM);
    printf("Full Path: %s\n", full_path);
    printf("Bytes written to storage layer: %d\n", b);
    printf("Waiting channel: %s\n", channel);

}
char *getUserName(int uid)
{
    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(uid);
    if (pw)
    {
        return pw->pw_name;
    }
    return "";
}
int getBytes(int pid)
{   
    FILE* statusf2;
    char path[40];
    char buf2[100];
    int storage_bytes;
    snprintf(path, 40, "/proc/%d/io", pid);
    statusf2 = fopen(path, "r");
    if(statusf2 == NULL)
        return -1;

    while(fgets(buf2,sizeof buf2, statusf2) != NULL){
    sscanf(buf2, "write_bytes:  %d", &storage_bytes);
    return storage_bytes;
    }   
}
char *getPath(int pid)
{   
    FILE* statusf3;
    char path[40];
    char buf3[100];
    char *fullpath;
    snprintf(path, 40, "/proc/%d/cmdline", pid);
    statusf3 = fopen(path, "r");
    if(statusf3 == NULL)
        return "";

    while(fgets(buf3,sizeof buf3, statusf3) != NULL){
    sscanf(buf3,"/ %s", fullpath);
    return fullpath;
}
}
char *getWaitChannel(int pid)
{   
    FILE* statusf4;
    char path[40];
    char buf4[100];
    char *channel;
    snprintf(path, 40, "/proc/%d/stack", pid);
    statusf4 = fopen(path, "r");
    if(statusf4 == NULL)
        return "";

    while(fgets(buf4,sizeof buf4, statusf4) != NULL){
    sscanf(buf4,"[<c0227f4e>] %s", channel);
    return channel;
}
}
```

I'm getting information for Name,State,UID and Username and VmPeak. They are working the way I want them. But the other 3 are the problem I can't seem to make them work and I can't figure out the reason(Full path,Bytes written to storage layer and Waiting channel). So my question is how to access them and print the information.

Comment: The code seems to miss allocating anything to `char * channel` so reading to where it points invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you please show the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by alk, modify your getWaitChannel() to allocate memory for channel. You need free the memory later when the channel data is not required.

```
char *getWaitChannel(int pid)
{
    FILE* statusf4;
    char path[40];
    char buf4[100];
    char *channel;
    channel = malloc(1024);
    /* Add error handling for malloc failure here */

    snprintf(path, 40, "/proc/%d/stack", pid);
    statusf4 = fopen(path, "r");
    if(statusf4 == NULL)
        return "";

    while(fgets(buf4,sizeof buf4, statusf4) != NULL){
    sscanf(buf4,"[<c0227f4e>] %s", channel);
    return channel;
}
}
```

Check your code and see whether any other variable(e.g. fullpath) need memory allocation and perform step by step debugging by commenting some part of the code to catch the error.

Comment: I figure out what the problem is I can't access files io and stack because permission is denied. Do you know how to resolve  the problem ?

Comment: I think it needs root access. Try running the program from root user.

Comment: I am running it from root

Comment: are you able to display the content using cat command. cat "/proc/<pid>/io". If this works then the program should also work.

Comment: No, I can't that's how I figured that permissions are denied

Comment: Actually I'm not running as root.

Comment: But don't know my password for root

Comment: may be for testing purpose, you can use the pid of the process itself using getpid(), for example Replacing x with getpid(). and then you can test for other pids when you have root access.  get_info(getpid(), argc, argv);

Comment: I managed to make it working. Thank you very. I have access now. Only problem is I don't know how to print the Waiting Channel

Comment: allocate memory as shown above and print. it should work. Only thing you need to use scanf based on the data format.

Comment: Using `snprintf()` is great to prevent overflow, but not checking its result and then doing `statusf4 = fopen(path, "r");` is bad too.  Using a truncated `path` is not good error handling.